# NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException when reading data from a csv file using opencsv in java

Tags: java, csv, file-io, opencsv

im making an application to automate sending emails. Initially the csv file is read, and an instance of a Recipient class is made and that is added to an arraylist. However, i am getting a load of errors, including NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvException;


public class UserDataLoader {

    private final String url;
    private ArrayList<RECIPIENT> mailingList = new ArrayList<>();

    public UserDataLoader (String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void loadData(){
        try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(url))) {
            List<String[]> records = reader.readAll();

            for (int i = 1; i <= records.size(); i++){
                String[] record = records.get(i);
                String name = record[0];
                String emailAddress = record[1];
                String dateOfBirth = record[2];

                RECIPIENT customer = new RECIPIENT(name, emailAddress, dateOfBirth);
                mailingList.add(customer);
    
            }
        
        } catch (IOException | CsvException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<RECIPIENT> getMailinList(){
        return mailingList;
    }


}
```

Here are the exact errors:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils
at com.opencsv.CSVParser.(CSVParser.java:110)
at com.opencsv.CSVReader.(CSVReader.java:99)
at UserDataLoader.loadData(UserDataLoader.java:19)
at App.main(App.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
... 4 more

I should have expected no errors and am unsure where this has come from. I have downloaded opencsv, placed it into my referenced libraries in vscode, and all of the java files and the csv file are in the same folder.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError's I usually find are related to dependency mismatches in your pom.xml/build.gradle file (depending on which build tool you are using) I would recommend looking at the class not found and what version of that library it was removed in and then see which libraries your code is dependent on and then take it from there

Comment: Take a look at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 It may require just adding that dependency into your repo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

add it in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```